# Cancel Post Request after posting a form to an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it's possible to cancel a post after posting a form to an IFrame.

```
$form = jQuery("<form target='iframetarget' method=post><files...></form>"); 
$form.submit();
```

I need `$form.cancelPost();` or something like that to cancel that request.

Comment: You want to cancel a request after you make it? As in... retracting the request you've already sent? That's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, No, not in general - you probably want to ask why you need to cancel the upload. If all you want is to *maybe* stop the bandwidth consumption (cause its taking too long), then as @Diodeus suggested, removing the frame from the dom may work.

If you want to stop the *result* of the upload (e.g. publishing something) you'll need to also implement something server side to undo the effects of the post to handle the case when the data has already reached the server. e.g. have a hidden requestID in the form, and a undoRequestAction script server side which you call (with your requestID) in addition to removing the iFrame from the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the Iframe from the DOM. I guess that would be like closing the browser before you get the response.

Comment: I hope you know that simply closing the window doesn't necessarily stop the server from handling the request if the request has already reached the server...